# java.lang.NullPointerException when not selected spinner on android

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I used this code to show a prompt when the user did not select the spinner on my application :

```
      protected View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
      throws IllegalAccessException {

        if( position<0 ) {
            final TextView v= (TextView) ((LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
                    inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
            v.setText("--select one--");
            return v;
        }
        return obj.getView(position,convertView,parent);
    }
```

I got one problems when I want to try save my values from spinner when it's not selected,  it always returns null pointer from this line, such as:

```
  hubungan_pp.getSelectedItem().toString(),
  hubungan_pp.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

I have 55 spinners on my application, and when I click button save and I'm not selected my spinner it always return null pointer. My question is how I can get a null value when user not click my spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put a [default selection text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) like 'Select One' or default value. Or you can handle Null value check as follows:

```
String selected_text = "none"
if (hubungan_pp.getSelectedItem() != null)
{
    selected_text = hubungan_pp.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `hubungan_pp.getSelectedItem()` is `null` because the spinner is not selected. So when you call `.toString()` on it, it's logical that it returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: yup... so how can i handle null value when its not selected?

Comment: @AoyamaNanami See the answer of MysticMagic  :)